# How to crop and save a RenderTargetBitmap UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, itemscontrol, rendertargetbitmap

I have an `ItemsControl` which contains a `Canvas`(800x800px) and a collection of `Rectangles` at certain coordinates.
I can save the `ItemsControl`as a `RenderTargetBitmap` which is fine, but I need to crop it at a specified X,Y,W,H and then save it which I can't seem to figure out how to do.

I've tried clipping the `Canvas` using `Canvas.Clip` and then saving it afterwards but that makes my `Rectangles` move out of their specified coordinates (CollageX, CollageY), so the Canvas **needs** to be 800x800px.

**EDIT:** Or is there some way to `Clip` a canvas without it affecting the X and Y positions of its child elements?

Here's what my current code looks like.

**C#**

```
private async void SaveDesignBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    //Images
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MaskArea, (int)PrintW, (int)PrintH);

    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Canvas1" + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, displayInformation.RawDpiX, displayInformation.RawDpiY, pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
    <ItemsControl Name="MaskArea" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollageGrid}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="800" Height="800">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="CollageArea" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        Width="800" 
                        Height="800"                
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CollageGrid">
                <Rectangle Name="MaskBounds" Width="{Binding CollageW}" Height="{Binding CollageH}" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True"
                            Drop="Mask_Drop"  
                            DragOver="Mask_DragOver"
                            ManipulationMode="All" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" DragEnter="Mask_DragEnter" DragLeave="Mask_DragLeave" Tapped="Tap_Collage"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                            Canvas.Left="{Binding CollageX}" Canvas.Top="{Binding CollageY}" Fill="Transparent">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding CollageX}" Y="{Binding CollageY}"/>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: i will be delving into this by the end of the week, be sure to check back as will be surely posting an answer on that soon.

Comment: Consider using the WriteableBitmapEx NuGet package.  It adds lots of extensions methods to the WriteableBitmap class.  So you'd get your image from RenderBitmap, then convert to WriteableBitmap, crop, then save to file.
https://github.com/reneschulte/WriteableBitmapEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't clip it before you save: clip it when you save.

The BitmapEncoder has a [BitmapTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform) property which you can use to control how it is encoded, including scaling, flipping, rotating, and **clipping**.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Caplan that works a treat. For anyone trying to figure this out -  it really was just as simple as `encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = ClipSize;`

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i am not sure if this helps, but people looking up how to crop an image will sure enjoy this answer as its really clean and fast.

```
private async void GetCanvasBitmapRegion(Rect RegionToCopy)
        {
            try
            {
                CanvasDevice Cdevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();



                var croppedwidth = (int)RegionToCopy.Width;
                var croppedheight = (int)RegionToCopy.Height;

                //create a new empty image that has the same size as the desired crop region
                var softwareBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, croppedwidth, croppedheight,
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                //based on this empty software bitmap we create a new CanvasBitmap
                var croppedimage = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(Cdevice, softwareBitmap);

                // this is the image we want to crop from, CanvasBitmap has lots of static initializers that like CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync 
                //or CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes
                CanvasBitmap initialimage = _image;

                if (initialimage != null)
                {

                    //this function does the cropped region copy.
                    croppedimage.CopyPixelsFromBitmap(_image, 0, 0, (int)RegionToCopy.Left, (int)RegionToCopy.Top, (int)RegionToCopy.Width, (int)RegionToCopy.Height);


                   //you can now do whatever you like with croppedimage, including using its .SaveAsync or replace the old one with it.
                }

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

            }
        }
```